# Is there any way to enable a backup of the current directory to take place when an rm command is issued?

Tags: bash, terminal, backup, iterm2, rm

I know how dangerous `rm` can be, and I'm unfortunately not a very responsible person at all. I know that I need to learn, but while I'm in the process, I need some help.

Is there any way to create a backup of a directory in another location when an `rm` command is issued? For example while working with a database, if you're in a protected mode you can "roll back" the system to the previous command. Is there a script to do this through bash?

I use iTerm 2 with support for script triggering with RegEx if that helps. I've figured out how to do it, but I need a more efficient way. Currently, I just `cp` the whole directory to another safe place when `rm` is typed into the terminal. In case I make a mistake, I just copy that back to its original place. Is there any way in which this can be done purely through bash, or is there a better way to do it using iTerm, where I can use a simple command to "roll back" to the previous state?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is: you can create a "`Recycle Bin`" for it:

1. Run `mkdir /home/<your_username>/.recycle`
2. Edit `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` file and append:

```
alias rm='mv -t /home/<your_username>/.recycle'
```

3. Save and close the file.
4. Activate alias by typing: `source ~/.bash_aliases`

For some people it's a bad idea.

---

Second option:

Take a look at this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379142